# Vim paste behaviour

Tags: vim, paste

I am a bit of a beginner when it comes to Vim and it is currently irritating me in many ways. One of which is the following:

Say i have the following text in a file

```
one  
two  
three  
four  

dog  
frog  
log  
mog
```

and I have used visual mode to select the number words (4 lines) if I then use P to paste at the 'd' in dog i get the following:

```
one
two
three
four


one  dog
two  frog
threelog
four mog
```

My desired output would be:

```
one
two
three
four


one
two
three
four
dog  
frog 
log
mog
```

I've noticed that it behaves as I expect if i do a y4y instead of visually selecting the lines. So what is causing the difference in behavior that I am seeing? and how can I get my visually selected block to paste as I would like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you are entering into the Visual [Block selection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#CTRL-V) mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>).

To get your desired output, enter into a [*Linewise* Selection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#V) mode, just by pressing <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: See also: [Visual Modes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_editor/Vim/Modes#visual)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I new it was something simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Shift+V`, it selects line by line

Answer (score -1):

try

```
:set paste
```

before pasting.

Comment: Your answer works for most of the vim-paste related questions, but not this one. On a more serious note, use Aif's answer if you find vim being more smart and indenting your pasted text.